# Minecraft: score_name_min with score_name not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I was doing a command creation where I can create my own food in Minecraft.

One of my commands is this command, which is what I am talking about that is not working:

```
testfor @a[score_name_min=0,score_name=0]
```

The command block should say this if I am not tested, right?:

```
samplePlayer don't match the data structure... something like that
```

or if I am found, it should say:

```
Found samplePlayer
```

but instead of showing these responses, it shows none. Really none.

I also tried this using /give command, like this:

```
give @a[score_name_min=0,score_name=0] minecraft:carrot 1 0
```

but still the same, nothing happened. The command didn't respond, even though my score in objective `name` is 0.

My goal here is to get my exact score. Because if I just typed: `testfor @a[score_name_min=0]`, the command will test every entity in the world who has a score of `0` or higher at objective `name`.

So can anyone help me, how can I make this work?

My main problem, to make the problem more specific, is to make `score_name` work, because every time I use `score_name` only, the command won't work.

Comment: I think the "data structure" error message comes only if you match something with the selector, but not the NBT data. The error message in your case would be "selector [...] found nothing". Are you playing in 1.12.2?

Comment: Try `/say lalala @a[score_name_min=0,score_name=0]`, what do you get?

Comment: @Fabian I am playing at 1.8.9 right now.

Comment: @Fabian shows this on chat: `That player cannot be found.`

Comment: To your first comment: Then you should have said that in the question. Can you try if the same happens in 1.12.2? (Don't just upgrade and downgrade the world, copy it or you'll destroy it with the downgrade.)
To your second comment: What do you mean? I don't understand that sentence. If you mean I should look in chat, I can't currently, because my work laptop blocks it.

Comment: @Fabian I meant after entering your said command, it says `That player cannot be found.`

Comment: @Fabian the /say command you said worked at 1.12.2, the /testfor command responded and said: `selector found nothing... etc`.. thanks Fabian. but the another problem is how should I make the command work for 1.8.9?

Comment: Ah, now you edited it, now it makes more sense. To the other point: If it works in 1.12.2, why not use 1.12.2? Do you have to use it together with some mod? If yes, which one?

Comment: well, now, I'm moving to 1.12.2 :)

Comment: Ok... So why didn't you do that already? Why stick to an old version?

Comment: I thought 1.12.2 is complicated

Comment: unlike 1.8.9, just normal command blocks with clocks

Comment: 1.12.2 is much easier for commands than 1.8.9. On 1.8.9, you have to make clocks, get the coordinates for them, everything is delayed one tick from the initiation, you have to watch out for update order, the number of ticking blocks in a chunk section, ... In 1.12.2, you just put command blocks in a row.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted, if you can already (sometimes you have to wait two days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was apparently a bug in 1.8.9, the version you used. It is fixed in 1.12.2.

Comment: sorry if it's just now that I marked it.. I am very sorry..

Comment: No problem, there are people who take longer. And it's not mandatory anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any output appearing in your command blocks, you might want to turn the gamerule `sendCommandFeedback` to true instead, and then place your command block.

Comment: My `sendCommandFeedback` is ON `true`.

Comment: @scriptmastere02 Does the output box appear in the command block? If it doesn't you can simply press the x at the right.

Comment: It is on `O` before i tried the command, not in `X`.

Comment: + yes it is showing.

Comment: If you do this in a command block, the gamerule is `commandBlockOutput`.

Comment: @scriptmastere02 What happens if you do `/say @a[score_name_min=0,score_name=0]` in the chat?

Comment: @Mika nothing, no response at all

Comment: @scriptmastere02 What happens if you do /say @a now?

Comment: @Fabian same as `commandBlockOutput false`, nothing shows up, proving the command really won't respond.

Comment: @Mika what do you mean? I'll do `say @a`, without any scores based?

Comment: @scriptmastere02 Yeah. Gotta know if you don't have the score or just have a bug of some sort

Comment: @Mika the topic was answered by Fabian, thanks anyways :)

Comment: In what way did I answer anything? I just asked if it works in 1.12.2. Or is your solution now to just switch to 1.12.2? If yes, why haven't you started in 1.12.2 anyway, if no, then I didn't solve it. Or is the solution really the gamerule? Because you said something else before.

Comment: @scriptmastere02 In 1.8, when a command uses a selector that can potentially obtain multiple targets (`@a` without `c=1`), and does not obtain any targets at all, nothing will be shown in the output. The gamerule will not fix this, as it's just a lack of a message being sent in the first place (which is fixed in the most recent version). This indicates that you did not actually have the score since no message was provided. If you were using any mods at all, they may have interfered, as mods and command mechanics rarely mix well.